# expressjs remove cookies from subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, connect

I am serving all static content on my app through a subdomain.

However, my express app is still setting session cookies on the static content. I tried setting the path like this as per the docs:

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'your app secret',
    cookie: {
        domain : '.yourdomain.com'
    },
    store: new MongoStore({
        db: 'db',
        host: 'localhost',
        port:config.dbPort
    })
}));
```

but it still doesn't work for me. I also tried using 'path' :

```
cookie: {
   path : '.yourdomain.com'
}
```

but even that doesn't prevent setting of cookies on static content.

Any ideas on how to remove cookies from all static content?

**UPDATE:**

```
Request Headers
    Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
    Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:cdn.yourdomain.com
    Referer:http://localhost:8888/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5

Response Headers
    Cache-Control:public, max-age=86400
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8
    Date:Mon, 28 May 2012 09:02:09 GMT
    Last-Modified:Tue, 01 May 2012 03:57:45 GMT
    Server:nginx
    Set-Cookie:connect.sid=d9nEPGiAeSwGFUN2Ra8CGBmq.tPdTQdk7O2UUvO2q%2BEOG2%2Fgh%2FNEdIxtUZYdUN%2FtDmas; domain=www.yourdomain.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 28 May 2012 13:02:08 GMT; httpOnly
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    X-Cache:MISS
    X-Edge-Id:353260802
```

Comment: When you set the domain to `.yourdomain.com`, you are instructing the browser to use this cookie for **any** subdomain. You probably only want to set it for www.yourdomain.com instead.

Comment: How about pasting more of your config? Is the logic for the subdomain the same as the logic from your main site? (is there 1 app that checks for the domain or ..?)

Comment: @alessioalex There is just a single app living at www.yourdomain.com. The subdomain is cdn.yourdomain.com. I see cookies in the request-response headers for my static content being served from cdn.yourdomain.com

Comment: @zi42 I tried that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connect session middleware works this way. Cookies are set regardless of the current host. This is good from a performance point of view, but inherently causes issues like this.

I see two solutions for this issue:

- Use [Connect's Vhost](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html) middleware. IMO, this is the most straightforward solution. Just create a separate app for `cdn.yourdomain.com` without including the session middleware for it.
- Create a wrapper around the session middleware in order to include it only for requests with the correct host. This is a pretty odd solution, and can disturb other middleware like CSRF.

Anyway, I would say that using Node.js for serving static assets may look like a strange idea. For this, web servers like Nginx are unbeatable in terms of performance and lightness. Requests for static requests should ideally not even reach Node.js.

--

FYI, code for the second solution could look like that (untested):

```js
function hostAwareSessionMiddleware(options) {
  var originalMiddleware = express.session(options);
  if(!options.cookie || !options.cookie.domain) return originalMiddleware;
  var domain = options.cookie.domain;
  if(domain[0] === '.') domain = '(.+)\.' + domain.slice(1);
  var regex = new RegExp('^' + domain.replace('.', '\\.') + '$', 'i');
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.headers.host) return next();
    if(req.headers.host.match(regex)) {
      return originalMiddleware(req, res, next);
    }
    next();
  }
}

app.use(hostAwareSessionMiddleware({
  secret: 'your app secret',
  cookie: {
    domain : 'yourdomain.com'
  },
  store: new MongoStore({
    db: 'db',
    host: 'localhost',
    port:config.dbPort
  }
}));
```