# Not able to delete cookie in expressjs from subdomain

Tags: javascript, express, cookies

I am in URL `q-xyz.abc.co.za` I need to delete cookie which domain is set as `.abc.co.za` httpOnly and secure

I have implemented to delete in express

```
res.clearCookie("cookiename",{ domain : ".abc.co.za" , path:"/"})
```

But its not clearing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [expressjs remove cookies from subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781187/expressjs-remove-cookies-from-subdomain)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski no